# Using GET and POST vs getter and setter methods (URLS)

Tags: html, http, network-protocols

As a trained programmer, I have been taught, repeatedly to use getter and setter methods to control the access and modification of class variables.  This is how you're told to do it in Java, Python, C++ and pretty much every other modern language under the sun.  However, when I started learning about web development, this seemed cast aside.  Instead, we're told to use one URL with GET and POST calls, which seems really odd.

So imagine I have a `Person` object and I want to update their age.  In the non-HTTP world, you're supposed to have a method called `<PersonObject>.getAge()` and another method called `<PersonObject>.setAge(int newAge)`.  But say, instead, you've got a webserver that holds user profile information.  According to HTTP conventions, you'd have a URL like '/account/age'.  To get their age, you'd request that URL with a 'GET', and to set their age, you'd request that URL with a 'POST' and somehow (form, JSON, URL-arg, etc.) send the new value along.

The HTTP method just feels awkward.  To me, that's analogous to changing the non-HTTP version to one method called `age`, and you'd get their age with `<PersonObject>.age('GET')`, and set their age with `<PersonObject>.age(newAge, 'SET')`.  Why is it done that way?

Why not have one URL called '/account/getAge' and another called '/account/setAge'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are refering to is a RESTful API. While not required (you could just use getters and setters) it is indeed considered good practice. This however does not meen you have to change the code of your data objects. I always use getters and setters for my business logic in the models layer.

What you are talking to through the HTTP request are the controllers however, and they rarely use getters and setters (I suppose I do not need to explain the MVC design pattern to an experienced programmer). You should never directly access your models through HTTP (how about authentication and error handling and stuff...)

If you have some spare time I would advise you to have a look at this [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpAhXa12xvU), which I found very useful.

Comment: I just watched that screencast and it was very informative.  I don't really like with the GET,POST,PUT,DELETE paradigm, but I thought a lot of the other things he presented in the video were really good.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could have separate URLs if you like, but getters and setters can share names in the original context of your question anyway because of overloading.

```
class Person {
    private age;
    public age() {
        return this.age;
    }
    public age(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

So if it helps you, you can think of it like that.